# Daily cron task at certain hour?

Tags: cron

I want to run a command everyday but I am not sure how to do it correctly with the cron task.

I understand this is the code I need to know:

```
* * * * * command to be executed
- - - - -
| | | | |
| | | | ----- Day of week (0 - 7) (Sunday=0 or 7)
| | | ------- Month (1 - 12)
| | --------- Day of month (1 - 31)
| ----------- Hour (0 - 23)
------------- Minute (0 - 59)
```

If I do this `* * * * *` this mean it runs every minute, right?

What about everyday, particularly `each day at 1AM`?

Is it this `0 0 * * *` for running the command everyday?

Comment: https://crontab.guru/every-day-at-1am

Comment: 0 0 * * * will run it every day - more specifically, it will run it at *midnight* (00:00)... ie. when minute is 0 and hour is 0.  To run it at 1AM, you'd use 0 1 * * * (minute=0, hour=1 ie. 01:00)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
0 1 * * * command > /dev/null 2>&1
```